# Apache HttpClient get status code along with all redirection url

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to get the status code of each redirected URL (with URL). I know there is a way through which we can get all redirection URLs by passing HttpClientContext but I want a status code as well. Is there any way to get a status code as well along with url?

```
                var httpget = new HttpGet("www.dummy-url.com");
                try (final var closeableHttpResponse = closeableHttpClient().execute(httpget, context);) {
                    final var instream = closeableHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    instream.close();
                    List<URI> redirectURIs = context.getRedirectLocations();
                    EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom response interceptor to capture all incoming response messages

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .addInterceptorLast(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.adapt(context);
                RouteInfo route = clientContext.getHttpRoute();
                HttpRequest request = clientContext.getRequest();
                HttpHost targetHost = route.getTargetHost();
                try {
                    URI uri = new URIBuilder(request.getRequestLine().getUri())
                            .setScheme(targetHost.getSchemeName())
                            .setHost(targetHost.getHostName())
                            .setPort(targetHost.getPort())
                            .build();
                    System.out.println(uri + " -> " + response.getStatusLine());
                } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                    // unexpected. do some recovery
                }
            }
        })
        .build();
try {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://google.com/");
    httpclient.execute(httpget, new ResponseHandler<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            return null;
        }

    });
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

```
http://google.com:80/ -> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
http://www.google.com:80/ -> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: This will log all url with status code but assume that i have created bean for `CloseableHttpClient` and I am calling from somewhere by injecting it. I see it doesn't give me control over response like if you saw in my code snippet i.e in description I can get all redirect URLs collectively i can decide what I have to same way I need status so that I can execute my logic based on that. Thank you

Comment: Ah, a little bit of programming, no?

Comment: Set attribute map in HttpContext( `var context = HttpClientContext.create();context.setAttribute("url", new HashMap<String, Integer> ());closeableHttpClient().execute(httpget, context)`) and add URL and status code ( in interceptor). This way I can get both URL and status code :).